# Building Settings.apk for Glass

Tags: java, android, google-glass

I am trying to build Settings.apk for Glass as demoed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OPethpwuYEk#t=500s

I've cloned the source from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/

When I import the android project to eclipse. Every source file has errors because `com.android.internal.R` cannot be resolved to a type. Can anyone provide build instructions for this or other platform apps on the **android.googlesource** site?

Comment: The Settings.apk needs to be compiled from full source.  I am in the process of compiling it as we speak and will post once it is done. :)

Comment: Though it is not a direct answer to your question, here is the result of what you are looking for. :) http://www.glassxe.com/2013/05/23/settings-apk-and-launcher2-apk-from-the-hacking-glass-session-at-google-io/

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659552/modify-settings-apk-to-work-with-project-glass

Comment: @JeffThomas Hey do you able to compile the project ? Could you please post an answer ?